# WordPress sub-menu in sidebar

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, submenu

I'm creating an custom template for wordpress, and I got problem with menu. I want to create menu in the sidebar.

I got static menu like this:

```
        <ul class="purp_bullet">
        <li><a href="#sub-1">A/a>
            <ul id="sub-1">
                <li><a href="link">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">B</a></li> 
                <li><a href="link">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">B</a></li>                                   
            </ul>
        </li>           
        <li><a href="#sub-2">C/a>
            <ul id="sub-2>
                <li><a href="link">D</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">D</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">D</a></li> 
                <li><a href="link">D</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">D</a></li>                                   
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="link">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">F</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">G</a></li>   
    </ul>
```

With CSS like this:

```
ul.purp_bullet {
    list-style-image: url('img/list_bullet.png');
    padding-left: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.purp_bullet li a {
    color: #003366;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.purp_bullet li a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.purp_bullet li a:active {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: bold;
}
```

I want it to be fully dynamic, just like wordpress menus, when I go into menu section in admin panel and create my own menu from pages that i created, then drag "my custom menu" onto widgets panel (sidebar) so it shows up. Note that this isn't my main menu (I already got the menu in header).

Also there is one more thing I need to do.
I got pages like employers and when I'm on some employer page the menu must be expanded( or rolled down, sorry for my bad english :x), but when i'm on other page it must be rolled up.

Screens:

[When I'm on some employer page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ZL9.jpg)

[When I'm on other pages like contact etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWAqz.jpg)

Do i need create new menu in functions and then hook it like my main menu?

Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu

Comment: Ok, so i created in functions.php new menu -> register_nav_menus(array('side_menu' => 'side menu')); and called it in sidebar.php -> <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'side_menu','menu_class' => 'purp_bullet')); ?> but even if i assigned in admin panel locations of two difrent menus it shows me onlny my main menu

Comment: Don't call it directly.  Add it to your sidebar via the "Appearance" => "Widgets".  Also - did you go to "Appearance" => "Menus" and set up the menu the way you want it?

Comment: Yes i created separate menu, and set up it in widgets but it won't appear. Can you give me some advice, step by step what to do in functions, css etc?

Comment: This is my menu in apperance -> http://oi68.tinypic.com/aoo0oo.jpg and this is the effect i recive -> http://oi63.tinypic.com/a4pfo4.jpg on all pages i set up parent "Prof. zw. dr hab. Krystian Roleder" (page on top of the menu). When i "inspect element" in chrome i see my sub menu, but when i click on it, it just redirect me to my page "Prof. zw. dr hab. Krystian Roleder" and doing nothing more (it should roll down other elements right?)